# How to validate an integer using hibernate validator using GWT Editor framework

Tags: java, gwt, hibernate-validator

I am using hibernate validator together with the Editor framework to validate inputs against DTO's in my GWT project.

The problem I have is that the user is inputing a string in a text box, which should be validated as an integer. I have tried to apply the hibernate-validator annotations to automatically get it working but it seems I am missing something.

My DTO:

```
public class MyDto {  
   @Min(value = 1, message = "Radius must be at least 1 meter.")
   private int radius = 100;

   ...
}
```

I am using a GWT IntegerBox to read the value for the radius, and this works correctly when entering a value such as -1, but not when I enter a value that is not an integer, "hi" for example.

The only way I have found to validate this is to issue a getValueOrThrow() on the IntegerBox and then manually set the error. Is there no way to express this using hibernate-validator annotations directly?

I have tried using Integer and @NotNull, @NotEmpty, @Valid.

My current code looks something like this:

```
try {
    radiusBox.getValueOrThrow();
}
catch (final ParseException e) {
    radiusDecorator.setErrorText("Invalid radius value.");
    return;
}

final MyDto dto = editorDriver.flush();
final Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = clientValidator.validate(dto);

if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
    editorDriver.setConstraintViolations(violations)
    return;
}
```

Comment: I guess you want to use client side bean validation using hibernate validator (http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation) ?
So neither of the annotations  (`@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty`, `@Valid`) work?

Comment: If you don't call getValueOrThrow what value will be set in MyDto?